# How can I make this code efficient by looping?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have am trying to extract an image to display as a background image on my li elements.

The exact number of li's is undefined but my code is not efficient in handling this as I have had to manually write these in. I am not sure the best way to loop through this so that it does not require manual process when more li's are added.

```
$('.carousel').each(function(){ 

    var i = 0; 
    $(this).find("li").each(function(){
        i++;
        $(this).addClass('thumbnail'+i); 


    });  

    $(this).find("li.thumbnail1").css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).find('.item:nth-child(1) img').attr('src') + ')');
    $(this).find("li.thumbnail2").css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).find('.item:nth-child(2) img').attr('src') + ')');
    $(this).find("li.thumbnail3").css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).find('.item:nth-child(3) img').attr('src') + ')');
    $(this).find("li.thumbnail4").css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).find('.item:nth-child(4) img').attr('src') + ')');
    $(this).find("li.thumbnail5").css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).find('.item:nth-child(5) img').attr('src') + ')');

});
```

Comment: I don't understand. You are already looping through your li's and adding the class. Why not add the background image in that loop too? E.g. `$(this).css('background-image', 'url(...`

Comment: 1) you need to add more details to be helped... 2) Why add class and not assign the background directly into the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var that = this;
$(this).find("li").each(function(index){
    var imgSrc = $(that).find('.item:nth-child(' + (index+1) + ') img').attr('src');
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imgSrc + ')');
});
```

I think this makes more sense than what you're doing. The jquery .each function has an Index as the first argument so you can find the matching .item with the same index if that's what you need

Comment: You don't need the `.each()` because [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) can do this for you: `$('li', that).css('background-image', function(idx) { return 'url("' + $(that).find('.item:nth-child(' + (idx + 1) + ') img').attr('src') + '")'; });`

Answer (score 0):

When you use the $.each() function, you can pass some args to it. For example:

```
$(this).find("li").each(function(i, o){ });
```

Where **i** is the index, and *o* is the object itself (in your case, the *li* element).
So, you could try doing this:

```
$(this).find("li.thumbnail" + i).css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).find('.item:nth-child('+ (i - 1) + ') img').attr('src') + ')');
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting it like so is a bit more efficient.

```
$('.carousel').each(function(){ 
    var $carousel = $(this);
    $carousel.find("li").each(function(index){
        $(this).addClass('thumbnail'+index); 
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + $carousel.find('.item:nth-child(index) img').attr('src') + ')');
    });  
});
```

Storing your carousel the scope of it's `each()` allows you to interact with it in the scope of your `li`'s `each()`. There is no need to declare a separate `i` variable, as the first argument passed to the function in the call to `each()` is the index of the current item.